# SSL Proxy / Decryption?

Tags: ssl, encryption

One of my clients just received the software ordered from his chosen developers, asked me to look at it and prepare the hosting procedures.

It's an Java (jar) app, so far so good ... but I saw something suspect, every 60 minutes or so the software connects to a remote host :443 port using SSL and transferring ~ 3-10 MB of encrypted data (as POST) then closes the connection, this is very strange. Tried to wireshark it but everything is encrypted and I have no clue about what kind of data is transferred, I know only the destination hostname. The hosted data within the app will be highly sensitive (insurance-broker) and if my client decides to go with it - this is a serious issue for his business and also for his clients, I've asked the developer company about this and they said that no one added something like this even if I provided them the proff (pcap).

I can block it within firewall, but if they added something like this it could exist another hosts ready to receive the encrypted data.

The only way I can figure it out is to somehow decrypt the SSL traffic in order to read RAW data and give my client all the needed informations in order to talk with the developer company to sort it out, how can I do that ? With some sort of ssl-proxy or whatever ... tried to google it but didn't find any kind of relevant tutorials.

I have access to the physical machine which is running the Java application, I can see every single bit of the traffic but ... encrypted.

Comment: 1. Block it with a firewall. 2. Provide *your* client with your concerns and the proof you have so far, and with the developer's denials. It's fundamentally not your problem and not a matter that requires heroic efforts on your part to investigate, unless your client is willing to pay for it, in which case you should hire a specialist.

Answer (score 0):

If I was in your place instead of trying to decrypt ssl connection would have tried following steps:

1)Since you are aware of the host to which it is making a post request , find out more about that service so as to learn what it does ? May be try contacting that site saying that we need to consume your service what should I send my in post request ;)

2)Second way around would be if you can decompile the jar file and find line in the source code which makes that request and then you could go back to the developer asking as why this has been written. To find the source code which is making the call what you could do is block the host access on your firewall.
The code would fail and mostly probably he would have logged the exception in his log files. Find the stack trace and you will know the line of code that is
making that request.

Hope this helps.